# Websocket in Spring and Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp

For a project I'm building in Spring I'd like to implement websocket. I have found a solution in the form of STOMP, but I can not find a way to send a websocket message to a single user, only a way to do a full broadcast to all clients. What are good alternatives that plug easily into Spring and that I can use to send and receive messages? I have a self-rolled user system in Spring (rather than using Spring Security) and I want to tie it in with that.

Edit: I'd like to point out that I want a solution that degrades gracefully to other protocols for communication, in the way that socket.io does this.

Comment: http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html Sending Messages To a Single User section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using Spring with websockets, have a look at the new Spring [Websocket support in Spring 4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html), this is a [presentation](http://rstoyanchev.github.io/s2gx2013-intro-websocket-spring-framework-4/#1) about it.

According to the documentation, Spring supports connection a single user, as well as broadcast:

> Spring Framework allows @Controller classes to have both HTTP request
>   handling and WebSocket message handling methods. Furthermore, a Spring
>   MVC request handling method, or any application method for that
>   matter, can easily broadcast a message to all interested WebSocket
>   clients or to a specific user.

This is an example of a broadcast, which you already can do:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

According to the documentation, the way to not do broadcast and reply only to the calling customer is to ommit the `@SendTo` annotation:

> By default the return value from an @SubscribeMapping method is sent
>   as a message directly back to the connected client and does not pass
>   through the broker. This is useful for implementing request-reply
>   message interactions;

Comment: Well, for graceful downgrading, they both seem to refer to STOMP, but I don't find how I can send a message to a single person using STOMP, only to broadcast.

Comment: I have update the answer, connection to single client is also supported

Comment: Any idea on this question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565598/no-suitable-default-requestupgradestrategy-found

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
private final SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Bar","Foo"));

@AutoWired
public YourConstructor(SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate){
       this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay=1500)
public void sendMessages() {

for (String message : messages) {
   this.messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user, "/queue/messages", message);
        }
}
```

PS: @Scheduled Annotation for timed task