# No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm trying to run Websocket on Spring (Not STOMP but regular websocket) as seen [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html). However, after following the tutorial, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.socket.server.support.DefaultHandshakeHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable default RequestUpgradeStrategy found
```

I got this on several versions of Tomcat, the newest (which I assume really should have JSR 356 support) was a Tomcat 7.0.50

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your javaconfig/xml config and pom (the dependencies part)? Tomcat 7.0.50 works well with https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-websocket-portfolio/ and https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/, so it shouldn't be a Tomcat version issue.

Comment: I get the same issue and it works fine on the demo (spring-boot-sample) with the same build.gradle.

Comment: Also, it only happened after I fixed this.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24498638/spring-boot-4-not-rendering-jsps-throwing-404

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by simply updating to Tomcat 7.0.52.

Comment: I used 7.0.53 and it works as well. Seems that previous versions are not supporting JSR-356 specifications.

Comment: It does not help if one is using tomcat maven plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You need tomcat websocket if you use jetty

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```